# c++ template instanciation

Tags: templates, cmake, template-meta-programming

Lets say I have in a main cpp file a set of directive allowing to instanciate my binaries that implement an template algorithm with a given type using typedef and preprocessor directive for the choice of the type before compilation:

```
 #ifdef MS1
     typedef  MSVariableInterface1 InterfacorType;
  #else
       #ifdef MS2
           typedef  MSVariableInterface2 InterfacorType;
       #endif
  #endif

int main()
 {...        //use InterfacorType as the type for template
```

I would like my cmakelists to automatically compile the code with the different template instanciation knowing the different possible values for the preprocessor variables. Do you know how can I do that ?

Moreover I guess that this is not the correct way to deal with the problem, have you another suggestion to "unroll" the different instanciations of a (optionaly multi) template code given the set of type that can take each template. Such a solution will allow me to create a single binary to deal with all cases (with arguments allowing to choose the instanciation of interest) instead of creating a binary per instanciation. Thanks!

Comment: Not related to the question, but this code would be clearer if it was written with `#if defined(MS1) ... #elif defined(MS2) ... #endif`. No need for the nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable them using [add_definitions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3aadd_definitions):

```
add_definitions(-DMS1)
```